# How to remove main menu from drupal site

Tags: routes

I want to remove the main menu from my drupal site, however after unchecking that box in appearance the menu bar still persists. How can i permanently remove the main menu?

Comment: which theme are you using

Comment: under the menus tab, edit the main menu, then for links to display, choose no links

Comment: which theme are you using? the default theme or some other theme that you have downloaded